# ImportError: No module named deploy

Tags: python-2.7, import, paste

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# 
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# python 
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. 
>>> import paste
>>> import paste.deploy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named deploy
>>> from paste import deploy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name deploy
>>> from paste.deploy import loadwsgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named deploy
```

why i can import the paste,but i cannot import the paste.deploy.
i run the python by root,please explain it. i am a new python

Answer (score 2):

`paste` and `paste.deploy` are 2 separate modules.
You have to install both of them.

To install paste.deploy:

```
pip install pastedeploy
```

If it installed correctly, you should be able to run the following in the python interpreter to confirm it's available for use:

```
>>> import paste
>>> import paste.deploy
>>> paste.deploy.__path__
['/Users/joeyoung/.virtualenvs/reversemapping/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy']
```

> Packages support one more special attribute, ____path____. This is
>   initialized to be a list containing the name of the directory holding
>   the package’s ____init____.py before the code in that file is executed.

https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/modules.html#packages-in-multiple-directories

Comment: it has been installed.
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# pip install pastedeploy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pastedeploy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 1):

$ pip uninstall paste

$ pip install paste

Comment: Can you please expand on your answer? It's very basic at the moment and would help if you explained why this would fix the OP's issue

Comment: Well, I have no idea why, but this actually fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

first,uninstall paste or paste deploy
second,install paste deploy by follows:

```
$ hg clone http://bitbucket.org/ianb/pastedeploy
$ cd pastedeploy
$ sudo python setup.py develop
```

it will work well.